# How would I limit upload speed from the server in node.js?

Tags: performance, file-upload, upload, node.js, limit

How would I limit upload speed from the server in node.js?

Is this even an option?

Scenario: I'm writing some methods to allow users to automated-ly upload files to my server. I want to limit the upload speed to (for instance) 50kB/s (configurable of course).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do not think you can force a client to stream at a predefined speed, however you can control the "average speed" of the entire process.

```
var startTime  = Date.now(),
    totalBytes = ..., //NOTE: you need the client to give you the total amount of incoming bytes
    curBytes   = 0;

stream.on('data', function(chunk) { //NOTE: chunk is expected to be a buffer, if string look for different ways to get bytes written
     curBytes += chunk.length;
     var offsetTime = calcReqDelay(targetUploadSpeed);
     if (offsetTime > 0) {
         stream.pause();
         setTimeout(offsetTime, stream.resume);
     }
});

function calcReqDelay(targetUploadSpeed) { //speed in bytes per second
    var timePassed = Date.now() - startTime;
    var targetBytes = targetUploadSpeed * timePassed / 1000;
    //calculate how long to wait (return minus in case we actually should be faster)
    return waitTime;
}
```

This is of course pseudo code, but you probably get the point. There may be another, and better, way which I do not know about. In such case, I hope someone else will point it out.

Note that it is also not very precise, and you may want to have a different metric than the average speed.

Comment: That is a very ingenious approach. I will have to consider it. I'm sure I'm chasing a "not very good idea" but I wanted to see what would come of it.

Comment: @drachenstern, the idea is perfectly valid. There are a number of reasons for limiting upload speed. For example, you may want to offer premium plans or you may simply want to keep those uploading on your site for a longer period of time (higher interpretation rate of advertisements) among other reasons. I am not sure, but it might also spread resource usage more evenly and thus improve performance (but again, I'm not totally sure about this one).

Comment: ~ Uh, what? I'm the guy who asked the question, those were exactly the reasons I was considering it. I rather meant that this is Node, and it's intended to be fast and scalable (up and out at the same time) so that limiting upload speed may not be necessary. Additionally, I don't know that I can limit upload speed in node. It may not be fundamentally an option, and doing delayed accepts on the uplaods might be the only way to go, which is what this answer provides.

Answer (score 9):

Use [throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/throttle) module to control the pipe stream speed

`npm install throttle`

```
var Throttle = require('throttle');

// create a "Throttle" instance that reads at 1 b/s 
var throttle = new Throttle(1);

req.pipe(throttle).pipe(gzip).pipe(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of rolling your own, the normal way to do this in production, is to let your load balancer or entry server throttle the incoming requests.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth_throttling.  It's not typically something an application needs to handle itself.