# Expressjs/connect - Simulate slow file upload

Tags: node.js, express, jquery-html5uploader

Is there a way of setting a mode or value in connect or express
to simulate slow file uploads??

Comment: This has been asked before here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999882/how-would-i-limit-upload-speed-from-the-server-in-node-js

Answer (score 2):

First, install `node-limiter` then create a `Transform` stream that will throttle any `Stream`s:

```
var util = require('util');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
var TokenBucket = require('limiter').TokenBucket;

function BucketStream(rate, interval, parentBucket, options) {
    Transform.call(this, options);
    this.bucket = new TokenBucket(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, rate, interval, parentBucket);
}

util.inherits(BucketStream, Transform);

BucketStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {
    this.bucket.removeTokens(chunk.length, function(err) {
        callback(err, chunk);
    });
};
```

Then the request is a `ReadableStream`:

```
var bucketStream = new BucketStream(1024 * 500, 'second'); // 500KB/sec
req.pipe(bucketStream);
```

Now read from `bucketStream` (instead from req) as fast as you want, you'll only get 500KB/sec

I did this on top of my head so beware :)