# Express limit upload speed

Tags: javascript, file, express, upload

Is it possible to limit the upload speed of a file in express?

Example: The user has 10Mbp/s of internet and I want to limit then to only upload 1/10 of him internet speed.

I attempted to use the module **throttle** as this post says https://stackoverflow.com/a/32340972/13539397 but doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
const Throttle = require("throttle");

route.put("/api/upload", (req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(new Throttle(1)).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(join(__dirname, "./file.png")));
})
```

Comment: Define *"doesn't work"* .... doesn't upload or doesn't throttle? Any errors?

Comment: Doesn't throttle and the file come blank or with only a letter "c".
This "c" probably come from the initial letter from the file that i'm uploading to the server

Comment: I rather doubt this is something you can do from the server-side.  It's the client you want to slow-down, not the server.

Answer (score 1):

Use the package [`express-throttle-bandwidth`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-throttle-bandwidth) instead

```js
var express = require('express')
var throttle = require('express-throttle-bandwidth');
var app = express()
app.use(throttle(100000)); // limits to 100000 bps

app.put("/api/upload", (req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(join(__dirname, "./file.png"));
})
```

Since this limits the connection of the instance, use this instance only for file upload

You can also use [`express-throttle`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-throttle)

```js
var express = require("express");
var throttle = require("express-throttle");
  
var app = express();
  
// Allow 5 requests at any rate with an average rate of 5/s
app.put("/api/upload",throttle({ "rate": "5/s" }), (req, res, next) => {
    req.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(join(__dirname, "./file.png"));
})
```